# Rails 4 search bar

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a search bar in my Rails 4 app. I'm my user db has 'name' and 'email' columns for the user's - I want users to be able to search for other users by name or id.

I'm currently getting this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#index
Couldn't find all Users with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["name LIKE ?", "%hi@example.com%"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've looked at railscasts and a few forums etc but cant get past this point at the moment.

index.html.erb:

```
<% form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

model/user.rb:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    @users = User.search(params[:search])
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
  get     'search'   =>      'users#index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Rails 4? `find(:all, ...)` is the old way of doing things. find only takes ids now. Use:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search.present?
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    where(true)
  end
end
```

Also `present?` will test against both nil and blank. Keep in mind that LIKE can be really slow depending on your database.

Answer (score 0):

Searching in rails

By default rails doesn't support full text searching .Activerecord finder always find a record using the primary key ie. id.
Hence , we need some other gems or applications like sunspot, elasticsearch  etc..

i'll show you using Sunspot solr here ..

in the gem file of your application just add the following code...
.
    gem 'sunspot_rails'

```
group :development do
    gem 'sunspot_solr'
end
```

and in terminal use 
bundle install
rails g sunspot_rails:install

this will add solr and creates config/sunspot.yml file

rake sunspot:solr:start
rake sunspot:reindex

edit the user.rb lile in models 
app/model/user.rb

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchable do
        text :name, :email
    end
end
```

in app/controller/users_controller.rb

and then add in index function

```
def index
    @search = User.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
    end

    @users = search.results
end
```

Make a form to take a user input

```
<%= label_tag(:search, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:search) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks @amritesh! I was looking for a solution that didn't involve gems though